# Inserting 2 different sql insert into statements onto the exact same line

Tags: sqlite

```
def placeOrder_2():
    purchase_amount = int(input("Enter the amount different products you would like to purchase: "))

    for x in range(purchase_amount):
        p_id = input("Enter the ID of the product you would like to purchase: ")
        p_quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity you would like to purchase"))

        sqlstring = """
        INSERT INTO tblOrder_Line (costWhenPurchased)
        SELECT unitPrice FROM tblInventory
        WHERE itemID = ? VALUES(?)
                     """
        values = (p_id,)
        runsql(sqlstring, values)
        placeOrder_3(p_id, p_quantity)


def placeOrder_3(p_id, p_quantity):
    sqlstring = """
    INSERT INTO tblOrder_Line(orderNo, itemID, quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)
                """
    values = (p_id, p_quantity)
    runsql(sqlstring, values)
    placeOrder_4(p_id, p_quantity)
```

When i do this it will insert the values but on one row it will just have the "costWhenPurchased" and the others values are null, then on the row below it, it will have the other 2 values which should be in the same line as costWhenPurchased

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmjp3.png)

Answer (score 0):

This function is called when I save data to a SQLite DB
Gather up your variables and inset them

```
   Private Sub InsertTxData()

    '===============================================
    tbNewBal.Text = NewBal.ToString("#0.00")
    '=== This REMOVES the comma before SAVING
    '================================================

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            Try
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TxData (txSortDate,txYear,txType,txAmount,txCKNum,txDesc,txBalance,txSearchMonth)VALUES (@txSortDate,@txYear,@txType,@txAmount,@txCKNum,@txDesc,@txBalance,@txSearchMonth)"

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@txSortDate", DbType.String).Value = tbDateToday.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@txYear", DbType.String).Value = YEAR.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@txType", DbType.String).Value = tbTxType.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@txAmount", DbType.String).Value = tbAmount.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@txCKNum", DbType.String).Value = tbCKNum.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@txDesc", DbType.String).Value = tbDesc.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@txBalance", DbType.String).Value = tbNewBal.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@txSearchMonth", DbType.Int64).Value = intSearchMonth
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error " & ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
```